# Pure CSS/HTML/Javascript 2D Scrollable table with fixed column and header

Tags: javascript, css

I have a large table which might need to scroll both horizontally and vertically. I have seen lots of solutions for this but haven't found one that works that doesn't rely on jscript or similar. It seems like it should be doable but I've come up with problems. I think I can get the header row ok, but I am having trouble with the fixed column. I can't seem to get my body to extend beyond the viewport and my code is rendering very differently on IE8 and Firefox.
Can anyone give me any guidance?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function windowwidth(){
    var myWidth = 0;
    if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
        myWidth = window.innerWidth; 
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ||document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
        myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
        myWidth = document.body.clientWidth; 
    }
    return myWidth ;
}

function windowheight(){
    var myHeight = 0;
    if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ||document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
        myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
        myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
    return myHeight ;
}

function pageloader(){

var leftwidth=document.getElementById('left').offsetWidth;
document.getElementById('right').style.marginLeft=leftwidth+'px';

}
</script>

<style>

div{ border:solid; }
.left{ position:absolute; }
.right{ position:float-left; margin-left:50px;}
table,td{ border:solid; }
td{ width:200px; }
tr{ height:50px; }

</style>

</head>
<body onload='pageloader();'>

<div name=left id=left class=left>
<table>
<tr><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div name=right id=right class=right>
<table>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on it further though and came up with this solution. It works pretty well and is even pretty flexible. I think it's the best solution I've seen. Please let me know if you know of something better or know of a way to improve it.

The only thing I've found impossible to fix is the vertical-align which has to be top. Does anyone know of a decent, simple solution that makes IE8 respect vertical-align center for a td with a height?

Here is the demo: http://maymay.de/demos/table.html

And here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getStyle(oElm, strCssRule){
    var strValue = "";
    if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){
        strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oElm, "").getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
    }
    else if(oElm.currentStyle){
        strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1){
            return p1.toUpperCase();
        });
        strValue = oElm.currentStyle[strCssRule];
    }
    return strValue;
}

function pageloader(){
// get sizes of boxes
var leftys=document.getElementById('left').getElementsByTagName('td');
var lefty=leftys[0];
var barys=document.getElementById('topbar').getElementsByTagName('td');
var bary=barys[0];
var boxys=document.getElementById('topleft').getElementsByTagName('td');
var boxy=boxys[0];
var leftwidth=lefty.offsetWidth;
var topheight=bary.offsetHeight;
var boxwidth=boxy.offsetWidth;
var boxheight=boxy.offsetHeight;
if(topheight>boxheight){
var newtopheight=topheight;
var newinnerheight=bary.clientHeight-parseInt(getStyle(bary, "padding-top"))-parseInt(getStyle(bary, "padding-bottom"));
}else{
var newtopheight=boxheight;
var newinnerheight=boxy.clientHeight-parseInt(getStyle(boxy, "padding-top"))-parseInt(getStyle(boxy, "padding-bottom"));
}
// set new width for left column
if(leftwidth>boxwidth){
var newleftwidth=leftwidth;
var newinnerwidth=lefty.clientWidth-parseInt(getStyle(lefty, "padding-left"))-parseInt(getStyle(lefty, "padding-right"));
}else{
var newleftwidth=boxwidth;
var newinnerwidth=boxy.clientWidth-parseInt(getStyle(boxy, "padding-left"))-parseInt(getStyle(boxy, "padding-right"));
}
// apply widths and heights and margins
// alert ("newleftwidth: "+newleftwidth+" newtopheight: "+newtopheight+"\nnewinnerheight: "+newinnerheight+" newinnerwidth: "+newinnerwidth);
boxy.style.height=newinnerheight+'px';
bary.style.height=newinnerheight+'px';
boxy.style.width=newinnerwidth+'px';
lefty.style.width=newinnerwidth+'px';
document.getElementById('left').style.marginTop=newtopheight+'px';
document.getElementById('topbar').style.marginLeft=newleftwidth+'px';
document.getElementById('right').style.marginLeft=newleftwidth+'px';
document.getElementById('right').style.marginTop=newtopheight+'px';

// fix column widths and rowheights
colsync();
rowsync();

calcright();
// alert ("leftwidth: "+newleftwidth+" topheight: "+newtopheight);

}

function scrolling(){
if (window.pageXoffset) {
var xscroll=window.pageXoffset;
} else if (document.body.scrollLeft) {
var xscroll=document.body.scrollLeft;
} else if (document.body.parentElement.scrollLeft) {
var xscroll=document.body.parentElement.scrollLeft;
} else if (document.body.parentNode.scrollLeft) {
var xscroll=document.body.parentNode.scrollLeft;
} else {
var xscroll=0;
}
if (window.pageYoffset) {
var yscroll=window.pageYOffset;
} else if (document.body.scrollTop) {
var yscroll=document.body.scrollTop;
} else if (document.body.parentElement.scrollTop) {
var yscroll=document.body.parentElement.scrollTop;
} else if (document.body.parentNode.scrollTop) {
var yscroll=document.body.parentNode.scrollTop;
} else {
var yscroll=0;
}
var leftwidth=document.getElementById('left').offsetWidth;
var topheight=document.getElementById('topbar').offsetHeight;
var newleftmargin=leftwidth-xscroll;
var newtopmargin=topheight-yscroll;
document.getElementById('left').style.top=-yscroll+'px';
document.getElementById('topbar').style.left=-xscroll+'px';
}

function info(){
}

function calcright(){
// resize page to shrink to fit
var rchildrenr = document.getElementById('right').getElementsByTagName('tr');
var rchildrend = rchildrenr[1].getElementsByTagName('td');
var rcols = rchildrend.length;
var rsum = 0;
for (i=0;i<rchildrend.length;i++) {
rsum = rchildrend[i].offsetWidth;
}
document.getElementById('topbar').style.width=rchildrenr[1].offsetWidth+'px';
document.getElementById('right').style.width=rchildrenr[1].offsetWidth+'px';
}

function colsync(){
var topcells = document.getElementById('topbar').getElementsByTagName('td');
var rightrows = document.getElementById('right').getElementsByTagName('tr');
var rightcells = rightrows[1].getElementsByTagName('td');
var mypads=0;
for (i=0;i<topcells.length;i++) {
if (topcells[i].offsetWidth>rightcells[i].offsetWidth) {
mypads=parseInt(getStyle(rightcells[i], "padding-left"))+parseInt(getStyle(rightcells[i], "padding-right"));
rightcells[i].style.width=topcells[i].clientWidth-mypads+'px';
}else{
mypads=parseInt(getStyle(topcells[i], "padding-left"))+parseInt(getStyle(topcells[i], "padding-right"));
topcells[i].style.width=rightcells[i].clientWidth-mypads+'px';
}
}
}

function rowsync(){
var leftcells = document.getElementById('left').getElementsByTagName('td');
var rightrows = document.getElementById('right').getElementsByTagName('tr');
var mypads=0;
for (i=0;i<leftcells.length;i++) {
rightcells=rightrows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
if (leftcells[i].offsetHeight>rightcells[i].offsetHeight) {
mypads=parseInt(getStyle(rightcells[i], "padding-top"))+parseInt(getStyle(rightcells[i], "padding-bottom"));
rightcells[i].style.height=leftcells[i].clientHeight-mypads+'px';
// if (i==1) alert (leftcells[i].clientHeight);
}else{
mypads=parseInt(getStyle(leftcells[i], "padding-top"))+parseInt(getStyle(leftcells[i], "padding-bottom"));
leftcells[i].style.height=rightcells[i].clientHeight-mypads+'px';
// if (i==1) alert (leftcells[i].clientHeight);
}
}
}

window.onscroll = scrolling;

</script>

<style>
body{ margin:0; }
div{ border:none; }
.left{ position:fixed; background-color:White; z-index:0;}
.topleft{ position:fixed; background-color:White; z-index:1;}
.topbar{ position:fixed; background-color:White; width:1000000px; z-index:0;}
.right{ position:absolute; margin-left:50px; width:1000000px; z-index:-1;}
table{ border:none; border-spacing:0px;}
td{ border:solid; border-width:1px; width:5px; padding:2px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;}
tr{ height:5px; }

</style>

</head>
<body onload='pageloader();'> 

<div name=topleft id=topleft class=topleft onclick=info(); >
<table id=tabletable>
<tr><td>Fixed Block</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div name=left id=left class=left>
<table>
<tr><td>Row-0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row-1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row-2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row-3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row-4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row-5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row-6</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row-7</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row-8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row-9</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div name=topbar id=topbar class=topbar>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Cola</td>
<td>Colb</td>
<td>Colc</td>
<td>Cold</td>
<td>Cole</td>
<td>Colf</td>
<td>Colg</td>
<td>Colh</td>
<td>Coli</td>
<td>Colj</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div name=right id=right class=right>
<table>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>20</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>26</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>30</td>
<td>31</td>
<td>32</td>
<td>33</td>
<td>34</td>
<td>35</td>
<td>36</td>
<td>37</td>
<td>38</td>
<td>39</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>40</td>
<td>41</td>
<td>42</td>
<td>43</td>
<td>44</td>
<td>45</td>
<td>46</td>
<td>47</td>
<td>48</td>
<td>49</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>50</td>
<td>51</td>
<td>52</td>
<td>53</td>
<td>54</td>
<td>55</td>
<td>56</td>
<td>57</td>
<td>58</td>
<td>59</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>60</td>
<td>61</td>
<td>62</td>
<td>63</td>
<td>64</td>
<td>65</td>
<td>66</td>
<td>67</td>
<td>68</td>
<td>69</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>70</td>
<td>71</td>
<td>72</td>
<td>73</td>
<td>74</td>
<td>75</td>
<td>76</td>
<td>77</td>
<td>78</td>
<td>79</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>80</td>
<td>81</td>
<td>82</td>
<td>83</td>
<td>84</td>
<td>85</td>
<td>86</td>
<td>87</td>
<td>88</td>
<td>89</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>90</td>
<td>91</td>
<td>92</td>
<td>93</td>
<td>94</td>
<td>95</td>
<td>96</td>
<td>97</td>
<td>98</td>
<td>99</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```